# Changing order of integration in a double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The question was to sketch the region of integration and change the order of integration.
$$\int^{3}_{0} \int^{\sqrt{9-y}}_{0} f(x,y) dxdy$$

When I sketch the region of integration I do not see a way that it is possible to change the order of integration. 
My region is bounded by, $y=3$, $y=0$, $x=0$ and $x=\sqrt{9-y}$.
Any insight would help, if there is a way to do this then I guess I have it sketched wrong.
My image is below of what I drew

[image]

Comment: Looking at your sketch, you should be able to see that this is a simple region.  So what are the bounds on $x$?  Both of them will need to be constants, so what are the extreme values of $x$ in your graph?  Then figure out the bounds on $y$.  At least one of them would need to be a function of $x$.

Comment: Solve for y in your equation. Then, you want it in the order dydx, so first find the bounds for y given. Going from the positive y axis to the negative, whichever bound you encounter first will be your upper bound.

Comment: Does it really say $\sqrt{9-y}$ and not $\sqrt{9-y^2}$? It doesn't change anything important, but it looks a bit evil. Just saying.

Comment: Yes it says $\sqrt{9-y}$.

Answer (score 2):

The integration is performed over the region where $0\le y\le3$ and $0\le x\le\sqrt{9-y}$. This is the region shown below

[image]

So to change the order of integration, we need to define the upper $x$ boundary by a piecewise function or write the integral as the sum of two integrals:

$$
\int_0^{\sqrt6}\int_0^3f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
+\int_{\sqrt6}^3\int_0^{9-x^2}f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to express y in terms of x, and then figure out what that means about the bounds of x, which become constants.